# Web-based Git Repository Manager

Tags: php, git, version-control, open-source

I'm looking for a web based git repository manager.

I have found Indefero but It is pretty hard to configure. Does anyone knows any web based git repository manager(repositories,users and keys) that I could install in my server for free? Preferably PHP.

Thanks

Comment: Shopping and recommendation questions are not considered on-topic.

Comment: Ugh, I feel dirty now. Maybe best post/migrate to [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not php but I've heard good things about Gitorious (http://gitorious.org/gitorious)

Comment: _"System notice: Gitorious is being acquired by GitLab and gitorious.org will shut down end of May. Please import your repositories to [GitLab.com](https://gitlab.com/)_"

Answer (score 3):

[**ViewGit**](http://viewgit.sourceforge.net/)

> ViewGit is a git web repository viewer that aims to be easy to set up and upgrade, light on dependencies, and comfortable to use.

Requires PHP5. I've never used it before, but Zend Framework use it at http://git.zendframework.com